# Build Rejected by Apple due to LLVM instrument symbols or code coverage though none can be found

Tags: ios, xcode, code-coverage, testflight, instrumentation

I submitted a build to TestFlight recently and it got rejected with the following error:

> Invalid Bundle - Disallowed LLVM instrumentation. Do not submit apps
>   with LLVM profiling instrumentation or coverage collection enabled.
>   Turn off LLVM profiling or code coverage, rebuild your app and
>   resubmit the app.

Apple's [Technical Q&A](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1964/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40017675-CH1-SOURCECODE2) suggests to run the following commands to find if the build has any LLMV Instrumentation symbols or code coverage enabled but the results are negative.

```
$ nm -m -arch all <PathToArchive>/Products/Applications/<AppName>.app/<AppBinary> | grep gcov

$ otool -l -arch all <PathToArchive>/Products/Applications/<AppName>.app/<AppBinary> | grep __llvm_prf
```

An useful [gist](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/carlossless/9492d8e20938cfd1ee8163d7cdbfab9b/raw) by [carlossless](https://github.com/carlossless) also doesn't show any LLMV instrumentation symbols. Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the in-house SDK pod that was used in the app was built without the

> GCC_INSTRUMENT_PROGRAM_FLOW_ARCS=NO
>
> CLANG_ENABLE_CODE_COVERAGE=NO

flags in xcodebuild. When we used the following command to build the SDK, the build was accepted by Apple:

```
xcodebuild -workspace "${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.xcworkspace" -scheme "${FRAMEWORK_NAME}" -configuration "${CONFIGURATION}" -arch arm64 -arch armv7 -arch armv7s only_active_arch=no CLANG_ENABLE_CODE_COVERAGE=NO GCC_INSTRUMENT_PROGRAM_FLOW_ARCS=NO BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE=bitcode defines_module=yes -sdk "iphoneos" -derivedDataPath "${OUTPUT_DIR}"
```

This has been explained very well in this [article](http://blog.carlossless.io/xcode-9-and-carthage-coverage-data) by [Carlossless](https://github.com/carlossless).

Comment: I faced same problem in react native razorpay. solved using this answer.